# add quotes("") to a value in groovy

Tags: groovy

Even after googling a lot i couldn't find the solution for the query to which i'm going to ask so, please don't mind if its a silly question since i'm new to programming and this "Groovy" so here is my question.

I'm writing a script in groovy where it reads a file contains data like this

> `[a,b,c,d,e]`

I want to find the length/size, as groovy is not recognizing it as string i'm getting exceptions so, i need the above one as below i.e.

> `[a,b,c,d,e] ---> ["a","b","c","d","e"]`

please provide me the solution or let me know a way to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the file contain the literal text (String) `"[a,b,c,d,e]"`? Can you perhaps show the code that reads the data?

Answer (score 2):

In groovy, easy to perform operations on strings. Added a file `sample.txt` which contains `[a, b, c, d, e]`, for converting this to `List<String>`, used `collect` as

```
new File('../sample.txt').getText('UTF-8')
        .tokenize(',[]').collect { it as String }.asList().size()
```

Online IDE: https://ideone.com/06k6Nj